# jQuery UI Tabs - How to align an arrow

Tags: jquery, html, css

Firstly, I'd like to apologize for my english.

As you'll see I'm a newbie, so I'd really appreciate your help.

[Here's my code](http://dimenzije.net/jquery/demo.html)

And my question is ...
... how to align an arrow in the middle of the word in li tag (for example in the middle of the word *Other news* or *Tennis* or...).


Once again: **thank you very much** for your help! :) You're simply the best.

Comment: `Firstly, I'd like to apologize for my english.` why? I've seen worser English.. Could you post your code in a Jsfiddle= it´s easier.

Comment: Kees, thanks. :) Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/DpeLc/1/. :)

Comment: Instead of css arrow you can do this with background images.

Comment: hahaha, "worser English". That's funny!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DpeLc/4/)**

On `.usual a.selected:after`

In your CSS add `left:50%`

But you'll notice this is still in the wrong place, so you add a `negative left margin` as well, and set it to `half` of the `arrow width`.

Something like :

```
margin-left: -8px;
```

So you need to Add

```
left:50%;
margin-left: -8px;
```